# Visual Studio cannot handle nested submodule as expected

Tags: git, visual-studio, .net-core, git-submodules

I am having 3 solutions which

**Solutions**

Solution A

- `Project A1` is an extension project for System.Data.SqlClient classes (.NET Standard 2.0)

Solution B

- `Project B1` is a library used to manage some instances (.NET Standard 1.0)
- `Project B2` is a library used to manage the instances with the extended System.Data.SqlClient through `Project A1` (.NET Standard 2.0)

Solution C

- `Project C1` is a library depends on `A1` and `B1` (.NET Standard 2.0)
- `Project C2` is a NUnit Test depends on all project above (.NET Core 2.2)

**File Structure**

The Solutions/Projects are imported through Git submodules where the structure as below:

```
- \
--- \Solution C
------ \Project C1
------ \submodules
--------- \Solution A
------------ Project A1
--------- \Solution B
------------ \Project B1
------------ \Project B2
------------ \submodules
--------------- \Solution A
------------------ \Project A1
```

**Issue**

While I use Visual Studio to open `Solution C` and compile the projects inside, the results are various: (**note**: I didn't include `\Solution C\submodules\Solution B\submodules\Solution A\Project A1` in the solution since VS not allow 2 projects with same name)

- Project A1: ok
- Project B1: ok
- Project B2: *not ok*
- Project C1: ok
- Project C2: *not ok*

VS always said `Project B2` cannot find the `Project A1` (which path is `\Solution C\submodules\Solution B\submodules\Solution A\Project A1`), unless I right click on `Project A1` and select clean, then rebuild `Project B2` (clean is a must), below is the message:

`Error  NU1105  Unable to find project information for '\Solution C\submodules\Solution B\submodules\Solution A\Project A.csproj'. Inside Visual Studio, this may be because the project is unloaded or not part of current solution. Otherwise the project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore.`

However I tried to clone only `Solution B` to a new position (with submodules `Solution A`) and it can be compile and run as expected.

**Guesses**

- As suggested by @jessehouwing , this may be not a Git issue but Visual Studio, I guess it is due to VS is compiling the projects with 2 version of `Project A1` while I have already spent hours to ensure `Solution B` and `Solution C` loaded `Solution A` from the same branch and version.

### Update

**Guids**

- `Project A` of `Solution A`: FD9834ED-3C94-4445-AE15-DFF0F5C42656
- `Project A` of `Solution A` with `Solution B`'s submodules folder: FD9834ED-3C94-4445-AE15-DFF0F5C42656
- `Project A` of `Solution A`: **E0FEC3C6-42AB-47D9-912A-40B3C5D2BA66**
- `Project A` of `Solution C`: **2A7E2981-87F6-40A5-86F4-D523EC1F68DB**

---

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It would help to know the VS version you are using. In addition, this kind of questions (specially on closed source software) is usually best left to the vendor, i.e. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: It is VS2017 Professional, thanks

Comment: Solutions aren't referenced, Projects are. In Solution B or C, are you using project references or binary references. If using project references, are all indirect refereces part of Solution B or C?

Comment: Sorry my bad, yes solution A, B, C should be **Project** A, B, C. I am using project reference to the .csprj files. Project A need nothing other than .NET Standard 1.0 to compile while project B need Project A and NuGet package System.Data.SqlClient to compile for .NET Standard 2.0. Project C depends on Project A and B and System.Data.SqlClient (already installed) for .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Moreover, Project C is a NUnit Test project (.NET Core)

Comment: I suspect it has nothing to do with Git, but everything to do with the mix of NetStandard and .NET Core projects and the different ways nuget packages are restored between them. Can you update the above question with the right project types and replace solution with project?

Comment: @jessehouwing updated, also I have tried to remove the .NET Core NUnit test project and the issue remains

Comment: It looks like you have several solution files. Make sure that all solutions have the *same* project guid in the `sln` file and that it matches the project references in each project.

Comment: @jessehouwing please see the updated area for the Guids, however I cannot get the guid of `Project A1` to remain sames within `Solution A`, `Solution B` and `Solution C`

Comment: Hand edit all the project files while visual studio is unloaded and make sure all the guids are aligned across all `.sln` files, search&replace is probably your best friend here. Also make sure they have matching casing. Then reload Visual Studio. Each project must have a unique guid which must be the same across all solutions.

Comment: @jessehouwing sorry but the issue is still remains :(

Comment: Ahh now I see the issue. In your solution tree the SAME solution+project is included multiple times. That doesn't work! It never will. The recommendation is to create a single top level parent Git repo, mount each submodule project into it, keep a single solution file in the root Git repo only. Optionally create multiple of these root projects.

Answer (score 2):

After hours of research, it is confirmed a .NET mechanical issue which the same project is being saved across different location and be referenced by multiple other projects. Which .NET cannot recognize they are the same project even they are all cloned from git server and sharing the same name.

As `jessehouwing` suggested (thanks for all your help jessehouwing!!) we could wrap all projects(submodules) into one giant solution for development (I guess this approach match perfectly the name *solution*)

However what we are trying to do is having the below architecture:

- Cores.Library
- ACompany.Cores.Library
- ACompany.Cores.Web
- BCompany.Cores.Library1
- BCompany.Cores.Library2
- BCompany.Cores.Console
- BCompany.Cores.Web

So finally I decided to go for an internal NuGet feed while VS2017 already could auto generate the nupkg file on build which has been tested and working perfectly as expected.

@jessehouwing you may answer the question and I would set yours as the answer, thanks again!

Comment: Hi Zay, thank you for your sharing and so glad to hear that your issue is solved. Please mark your reply as answer when you have free time, that will help others to easier search this useful information.